# Invoke or Named Update?

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I am using Silverlight with WCF RIA Services. 
There is a class in my entity model called `Activation`. It has properties: `Code1` and `Code2` along with other properties.

On my silverlight client I need to send an `Activation` to the server where it picks out values from objects associated with it and populates the `Code1` and `Code1` attributes. E.g:

```
Public Sub ServerMethod(ByRef myActivation as Activation)
    Dim x as Integer = myActivation.Licence.NumberOfDays
    Dim y as Integer = myActivation.Product.ProductSeed
    myActivation.Code1 = GetCode1(x,y)
    myActivation.Code2 = GetCode2(x,y)
End Sub
```

Note that the activation codes are **not** persisted to the database, they simply go back to the client where the user can decide to save if they like from there.

What is the best way to achieve this using WCF RIA Services? At first I thought a named update in the domain service might do the job but there seems to be no Async callback for that.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why have you tagged this with `c#`?

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what the [InvokeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.server.invokeattribute%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) is meant for, just put it on your "ServerMethod". 
About the Async, every single call in wcf ria services is asynchronous and you have to supply a callback to the method if you want to be notified.
**EDIT:**
I didn't see in your question that you need to pass "Association" properties along the wire. In that case a NamedUpdate, though semantically incorrect, could be easier. Just remember that your context has to be "clean" or you'll submit unintended changes to the server (remember that you have to call the SubmitChanges on the DomainContext).
In case you prefer to use the InvokeAttribute, (and this is the way I'd go) then, yes, as you pointed out, return the "updated"  entity to the client and to workaround the problem with the association, use Serialization on your own, i.e ,Serialize your entity and send it to the server, than Deserialize server side and serialize it again before return it to the client, where you'll finally deserialize it.
I'm attaching a piece of code that I use both server and client side that I use with this purpose.

```
public static class Serialization
{
    public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        //Create a stream to serialize the object to.
        var ms = new MemoryStream();

        // Serializer the User object to the stream.
        var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (T));


        ser.WriteObject(ms, obj);
        byte[] array = ms.ToArray();
        ms.Close();
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array, 0, array.Length);
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string obj) where T : class
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (T));
        var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(obj));
        var result = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as T;
        return result;
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried decorating my ServerMethod with the Invoke attribute. However when I set a property within the method on a parameter like myActivation.Code1="blah", this change is not shown when returning back to the client. The only way around this I found is to return myActivation and when we are back in the client, copy all the required values from the return value to the original Activation. Is that the only way?

Comment: Also it seems like I can't access the entities navigation properties within the invoke method